# Find out if table has ever had records in it, even deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, modal-dialog

I want to show a view for the users if the **notes** column record doesn't have any entry previously. i.e ideally for the first time users.

If the user deletes the note after creating it (i.e even with 0 entries) I want it to show the same thing as if there were records in the table.

For this i can't do it simply with the counts like

```
@notes_list = current_user.notes
```

and in view

```
<% if @notes_list.count == 0 %>
      <%# view 1 %>
<% else %>
      <%# view 2 %>
<% end %>
```

So can you please help me out on this or is there any other better way than **if** check?

Comment: Sounds like the problem you want to solve is not one of counting records, but rather of recording the state of the user, whether they've ever seen/done something, to be able to educate them.

Comment: Yeah @JonathanAllard. i updated the user model with first_time? boolean. Have to change the view according to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new column to your `user` model named `note_created` as a **boolean** with default false value. Whenever a new user creates this field will remain `false`. But if the user creates any post you'll make it true for the rest of the time. If User deletes all his notes the field will remain true. And you can swap your views based on that field.

It may be a lame solution. But I don't have any better solution right now. :D

```
def create
  @new_note = Note.new(notes_params)
  if @new_note.save
    unless @new_note.user.note_created
      @new_note.user.note_created = true 
      @new_note.user.save
    end
   // rest of the code
  end 
end
```

Comment: Will try that out. But i think there is some other way to do it without creating a **new column**

Comment: Hey @Emu...Thanks man. its coming out well. added a new column to user model. But how can i change it to true for the first time when** @new_note.save** is success?

Comment: yeah for Mauddev's. But i think updating user model will help me in the long run. So that i can filter no of users without entry and only sign up.

Comment: sorry. don't use the callback. just after `@new_note.save`, check if `@new_note.user.notes_created` value is false or not. if false make it true

Comment: Sry @Emu. I am new to rails and i don't know what a callback means. This is what i did and its not working.                                                                 **def after_save
    current_user.update_attributes(any_entry: :true) if current_user.any_entry? == false
  end **    and called after-save under **@notes.save**

Comment: just after `@new_note.save‌`, check if ‌`@new_note.user.notes_created` value is false or not. if false make it true. You don't need the callback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82750/discussion-between-praveen-kj-and-emu).

Comment: Instead of these two lines `@new_note.user.note_created = true 
      @new_note.user.save` we can write a handy `@new_note.user.toggle!(:any_entry)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in one line, but how about this:
Add a toggle variable, default false. 
In your method def create note, set var to true. 
Destroy would not touch this var.
Make the if statement for the view with the toggle var.

Comment: Thanks @Mauddev. I will try to solve it as i am new to rails its little bit struggling for me. :)